# Python password generator

Tags: python, beginner, strings, random

This is considered as my second python project, I made the password generator where user has to input length of password minimum 5.

I made the code that it will guarantee at least one lowers case, one upper case and one special character is included in the password.
please review and comment.

```
import random


def letters():
    return list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')


def upper_case():
    uppercase = []
    for x in letters():
        uppercase.append(x.upper())
    return uppercase


def special_char():
    return list('!@#$%^&*()\'\"')

def all_char():
    return letters() + upper_case() + special_char()

def create_password(password, n):
    for x in range(n):
        password += random.choice(all_char())
    return password

def check_password(password):
    nletter, nupper, nspecial = [0]*3
    for x in password:
        if x in letters():
            nletter += 1
        if x in upper_case():
            nupper += 1
        if x in special_char():
            nspecial += 1
    if nletter > 0 and nupper > 0 and nspecial > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    n = 0
    while n < 5:
        n = int(input('Enter your password length (minimum 5): '))
    password = ''
    while not check_password(password):
        password = ''
        password = create_password(password, n)
        check_password(password)

    print('Generated password : {}'.format(password))

while True:
    main()
```

Comment: You could error check the user input, you can never trust people do what you ask. If I enter a letter it crashes. Good to get into the habit of writing comments as you write the code. It works, and that's the important thing

Comment: I added the following try statement ~

    while n < 5:
        try:
            n = abs(int(input('Enter your password length (minimum 5): ')))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter a valid number')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on what else has been posted, validating your inputs is necessary and you have a lot of functions and loops that can be removed.

#### String module

First, I would like to introduce you to the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants) module that is part of the python standard library. This module has string constants that you can import and use:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Using these would allow you to get rid of your first three functions (`letter`, `upper_case`, and `special_char`). Similarly to what Joe said, it would be better to make your character space a variable to avoid creating extra objects, and remove the `all_char` function at the same time.

#### `create_password` function

This function is clear and works okay, but can also be improved. As you are doing the same operation in each iteration of the loop (`random.choice`) this is and ideal scenario to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
# Before
def create_password(password, n):
    for x in range(n):
        password += random.choice(all_char())
    return password

# After
def create_password(n):
    return ''.join([random.choice(all_char()) for _ in range(n)])
```

This works by creating a list where a random character is selected from `all_char()` and then joining them all together. The underscore is a 'throwaway' variable here, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/3279716).

Alternatively, as we are already using the `random` module we could use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (but only in python3.6 and above) as this will return a list of `k` size:

```
def create_password(n):
    return ''.join(random.choices(all_char(), k=n))
```

#### `check_password` function

In general, simple statements are better than complex statements. Therefore, I would change the first line of this function to be:

```
nletter, nupper, nspecial = 0, 0, 0
```

As this is clearer.

The for loop works, and could be improved by using the `string` module constants, though they would need to be made into lists.

```
for x in password:
    if x in list(string.ascii_lowercase):
        nletter += 1
    if x in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
        nupper += 1
    if x in list(string.punctuation):
        nspecial += 1
```

Another way to test if two strings overlap is to use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); but this is getting more complex.

---

#### Altogether

```
import random
import string

def create_password(n, chars):
    return ''.join(random.choices(chars, k=n)) 

def check_password(password):
    nletter, nupper, nspecial = 0, 0, 0
    for x in password:
        if x in list(string.ascii_lowercase):
            nletter += 1
        if x in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
            nupper += 1
        if x in list(string.punctuation):
            nspecial += 1
    if nletter > 0 and nupper > 0 and nspecial > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
    n = 0
    while n < 5:
        try:
            n = int(input('Enter your password length (minimum 5): '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Not a number')

    password = ''
    while not check_password(password):
        password = create_password(n, characters)

    print('Generated password : {}'.format(password))

run = True
while run:
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        run = False
        print('Ctrl+c caught exiting')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! a lot of new subjects to go through and learn I will be looking more into using list comprehension, Can you explain more about KeyboardInterrupt exception

Comment: Because the `main()` function is running perpetually (`while True:...`) you exit your script by pressing `Ctrl`+`c`, which raises `KeyboardInterrupt`. By using `try:...except KeyboardInterrupt:...` we can handle the programme exiting more gracefully. There are other ways to handle this, such as the module [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), but catching the KeyboardInterrupt works nicely in cases like yours.

Answer (score 1):

#### Lots of lists

Every time you call `letters`, `upper_case`, `special_char` or `all_char`, you are creating a new list which will be no different from the other lists that were previously created.  You can make these variables that are assigned once and used everywhere.

#### Repeated checks

For every password you generate, you are checking its validity twice: once at the end of the loop, and the other on the `while` line.  The former serves no purpose, and should be removed.

#### Unused assignment

The assignment to `password = ''` inside your `while` loop is unused, and can be removed.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please don't forget to mark this as best answer if it worked for you.